# Is unfollowing someone on Facebook the same as unfriending them?

Tags: facebook

Is "unfollowing" someone on Facebook the same as "unfriending" them? If not, how do they compare?

Answer (score 2):

Unfollowing only removes them from your newsfeed. Unfriending removes them from your contact list. Note that your contact can't see you have unfollowed him but he can see you have unfriended him.

Answer (score 1):

They are not the same.

[Friending](https://www.facebook.com/help/240436879374301) means you are saying you want them to connect back with you. That you want to set up a connection where you and they are reading and seeing each other's posts. Think of this like catching up with an old friend and talking to each other about what happened in the last week. Two-way interaction.

[Following](https://www.facebook.com/help/www/279614732052951) means you just want to have their updates and posts in your timeline. But you do not necessarily care or want them to read your posts in their timeline. Like watching the news on TV, where the reporters tell you things, but they don't listen to your news. One-way interaction.

Unfollowing means you are stopping those updates from appearing in your timeline.

Unfriending means you are stopping those updates and you don't want yours appearing in theirs.

In both cases you are not told when someone [unfriends](https://www.facebook.com/help/110698549016637) or unfollows you.